# Spring boot, WebSocket doesn't send notification to the specified user

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket

I have such problem in sending notification to the specified user.
This is my config file.

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    //registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
}
```

This one is my client code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
connect();
```

}

```
function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function () {
    stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", function (notification) {
        console.log("------------------------ subscribed !!!!!!");
        notify(JSON.parse(notification.body).content);
    });
});
```

}

This controller handles all chat related handler methods

```
@MessageMapping("/message")
@SendToUser("/queue/reply")
public ChatMessage processMessageFromClient(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) throws Exception {
    return chatMessage;
}
```

Guys seems I am new in Spring boot websocket sphere, and please tell me whether or not it is enough for sending notification to the specified user.
Instead, when I execute the aforementioned client code, it's me, the user principal, who gets notified, not the needed user. What have I done wrong here? 
It says, that spring boot keeps the session id under the hood, and uses it to resole who to send the notification. But seems it is not the case here...

Here is the browser log, when notification send button is clicked.

```
Opening Web Socket...
stomp.min.js:8 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.min.js:8 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000
stomp.min.js:8 <<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:hmkhitaryan
stomp.min.js:8 connected to server undefined
stomp.min.js:8 >>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/user/queue/reply
stomp.min.js:8 >>> SEND
destination:/app/message
content-length:71
{"sender":"hmkhitaryan","content":"friend request","type":"FR_REQUEST"}
stomp.min.js:8 <<< MESSAGE
destination:/user/queue/reply
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:xgec4kaf-15
content-length:71
{"type":"FR_REQUEST","content":"friend request","sender":"hmkhitaryan"}
```

The thing is, that instead of sending "`hmkhitaryan1`", the next user, it sends to me, "`hmkhitaryan`".

Comment: See the error log

Comment: Dear manikant gautam, there are not error logs in the server side.

Comment: I think since you are sending to a `/user/queue/reply`, that means all users connected to this channel will get a message, in that case, both users. You need to send to specific channel like `/user/{user_id}/queue/reply`

Comment: maybe "/{user_id}/queue/reply" ? because @SendToUser annotation already does the job, inserts "user" word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convertandSend to reply to specific user. Like this -

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations  template ;


@MessageMapping("/message")
public void greeting(@Payload String message, 
          Principal principal){

    template.convertAndSendToUser(<userName_youwant_tosend>,"/queue/queue1",message);
 }
}
```

and in your config class -

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/queue","/user");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

I was facing the same problem with sendToUser. But this worked for me.Hope it helps.

Comment: Dear @yashpandey, what do you mean "queue1" , by writing "/queue/queue1" ? do you mean "queue/reply" ?

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan yes, /queue/reply, just replace queue1 with reply

Comment: Sorry, but did not work

`@MessageMapping("/message")
    public void greeting(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, Principal principal) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(chatMessage.getReceiver(), "/queue/reply", chatMessage.getContent());
    }`

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan did you put "/user" in setUserDestinationPrefix and  enableSimpleBroker ?

Comment: `@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue", "/user");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }
`

Comment: I have some implementation here, you can check https://github.com/yashpandey8055/SimpleWebsocketExample